# Can you use AWS Route 53 latency based routing to resolve servers outside AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, devops

I use AWS Route 53 for DNS management and I have servers and load balancers running on-premise or in any cloud outside AWS. I want to do global load balancing using AWS Route 53 latency-based routing. Is this achievable and a common use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route53 latency record has nothing to do with the record value or target IP, when you choose the latency based routing, you define regions and Route53 just looks the resolver IP which is making dns query and looks which is good to them in terms of latency with respective to the region and give that result.
You need to make sure your your records are correct, means the mapping of DC IP is associated with correct regions, the rest of it, Route53 will has all information e.g: resolver, latency etc